# Subtract values from maximum value within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Trying to take a df and create a new column thats based on the difference between the Value in a group and that groups max:

```
Group Value
A     4
A     6
A     10   
B     5
B     8
B     11
```

End up with a new column "from_max"

```
from_max
6
4
0
6
3
0
```

I tried this but a ValueError:

```
df['from_max'] = df.groupby(['Group']).apply(lambda x: x['Value'].max() - x['Value'])
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Option 1**
vectorised `groupby` + `transform`

```
df['from_max'] = df.groupby('Group').Value.transform('max') - df.Value

df
  Group  Value  from_max
0     A      4         6
1     A      6         4
2     A     10         0
3     B      5         6
4     B      8         3
5     B     11         0
```

---

**Option 2**
index aligned subtraction

```
df['from_max'] = (df.groupby('Group').Value.max() - df.set_index('Group').Value).values

df
  Group  Value  from_max
0     A      4         6
1     A      6         4
2     A     10         0
3     B      5         6
4     B      8         3
5     B     11         0
```

Answer (score 7):

I think need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`:

```
df['from_max'] = df.groupby(['Group'])['Value'].transform(lambda x: x.max() - x)
```

Or:

```
df['from_max'] = df.groupby(['Group'])['Value'].transform(max) - df['Value']
```

Alternative is [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by aggregate `max`:

```
df['from_max'] = df['Group'].map(df.groupby(['Group'])['Value'].max()) - df['Value']
```

---

```
print (df)
  Group  Value  from_max
0     A      4         6
1     A      6         4
2     A     10         0
3     B      5         6
4     B      8         3
5     B     11         0
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `reindex`

```
df['From_Max']=df.groupby('Group').Value.max().reindex(df.Group).values-df.Value.values
df
Out[579]: 
  Group  Value  From_Max
0     A      4         6
1     A      6         4
2     A     10         0
3     B      5         6
4     B      8         3
5     B     11         0
```